# Populate hash on the fly: keys in one file and values in another

Tags: perl, file, file-io, hash

So I have a text file with the following line:

> 123456789

But then I have a second file:

> 987654321

So how can I make the first file's contents the `keys` in a hash, and the second file's values the `values`? (Each character is a key/value)

Should I store each file into different arrays and then somehow merge them? How would I do that? Anything else?

Honestly, I would give you my code I have tried, but I haven't the slightest idea where to start.

Comment: You added a bounty, but you didn't explain what's wrong/missing from the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP mentions that each character is a key or value, by this I take it that you mean that the output should be a hash like `( 1 => 9, 2 => 8, ... )`. The OP also asks:

> Should I store each file into different arrays and then somehow merge them? How would I do that?

This is exactly how this answer works. Here `get_chars` is a function that reads in each file, splits on every char and returns that array. Then use `zip` from [`List::MoreUtils`](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) to create the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'zip';

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

my @file1chars = get_chars($file1);
my @file2chars = get_chars($file2);

my %hash = zip @file1chars, @file2chars;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;

sub get_chars {
  my $filename = shift;
  open my $fh, '<', $filename 
    or die "Could not open $filename: $!";

  my @chars;
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @chars, split //;
  }
  return @chars;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash slice.

If each line is a key/value: (s///r requires 5.14, but it can easily be rewritten for earlier versions)

```
my %h;
@h{ map s/\s+\z//r, <$fh1> } = map s/\s+\z//r, <$fh2>;
```

If each character is a key/value:

```
my %h;
{
   local $/ = \1;
   @h{ grep !/\n/, <$fh1> } = grep !/\n/, <$fh2>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) both files and [read them line by line](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) simultaneously:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

my %hash;
open my $keyFile, '<', 'keyfileName';
open my $valueFile, '<', 'valuefileName';

while(my $key = <$keyFile>) {
   my $value = <$valueFile>;
   chomp for $key, $value;       
   $hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

Of course this is just a quick sketch on how it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator madness:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use autodie;
use strict; use warnings;

my $keyfile_contents = join("\n", 'A' .. 'J');
my $valuefile_contents = join("\n", map ord, 'A' .. 'E');

# Use get_iterator($keyfile, $valuefile) to read from physical files

my $each = get_iterator(\ ($keyfile_contents, $valuefile_contents) );

my %hash;
while (my ($k, $v) = $each->()) {
    $hash{ $k } = $v;
}

use YAML;
print Dump \%hash;

sub get_iterator {
    my ($keyfile, $valuefile) = @_;

    open my $keyf, '<', $keyfile;
    open my $valf, '<', $valuefile;

    return sub {
        my $key = <$keyf>;
        return unless defined $key;
        my $value = <$valf>;
        chomp for grep defined, $key, $value;
        return $key => $value;
    };
}
```

Output:

```
C:\temp> yy
---
A: 65
B: 66
C: 67
D: 68
E: 69
F: ~
G: ~
H: ~
I: ~
J: ~
```

Answer (score -1):

I would write

```
my %hash = ('123456789' => '987654321');
```